# Making a grouped bar chart with two Y-axis with highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to build a grouped barchart based on two Y-axis with the package highcharter.

I'd like to get something similar to the picture below:

[image]

Here is a dummy dataset:

```
dummy_df <- data.frame(Label = c("A","B", "C"),
                                     value1 = c(34,59,12),
                                     Value2 = c(397,2678,212))
```

Output with a single Y-axis:

```
dummy_df %>% 
    hchart('bar', hcaes(x = 'Label', y = 'value1', group = 'value1'))
```

Comment: I would dissuade you from this form of visualization. This blog post offers the reasons why and what to do instead: https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/

Comment: I'm aware of the downsides of this form of visualization but the plot I wanna produce is quite straighforward and it will not alter the comprehension of the chart !

Comment: Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/du4261zq/) chart with the configuration as in your screenshot, in javaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dummy_df <- data.frame(Label = c("A","B", "C"),
                       value1 = c(34,59,12),
                       value2 = c(397,2678,212))



highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(type="column",name = "Order Items <b>Count</b>", data = dummy_df$value1 )%>%
  hc_add_series(type="column",name = "Order Items <b>Total Gross Margin</b>", data = dummy_df$value2, yAxis =1 )%>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = dummy_df$Label)%>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(lineWidth = 0,
         title = list(text = "Order Items <b>Count</b>")),
    list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE,
         title = list(text = "Order Items <b>Total Gross Margin</b>"))
  )
```

Gives you: [image]